# Pi 3 Model B does not boot. Shows only 2 multicolored squares

Tags: pi-3, power, boot-issues

I have a Raspberry Pi Model 3 B and it won't boot but instead shows a big multi-colored square in the middle of the screen and a little multi-colored square in the top right corner of the screen. I just received the Pi from a friend and haven't got it to boot since receiving it so there's no warranty. Help.

Comment: I'm sorry but you have not given us much info to go off. Could you tell us what SD card and operating system you are using?

Comment: @DarthVader The little rainbow square is explicitly a [power supply problem](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/display/troubleshooting.md).  If it just flickers intermittently, it may still boot, but if it is on solid, it probably won't,  so at this point it doesn't even matter if there is an SD card in it, much less what is on it.  Very likely the red PWR led isn't lit either, which is a correlate of this.

Comment: make sure your power supply can provide at least 1A (amp). try unplugging your keyboard and mouse. insufficient power is my guess as well.  if your power supply reads 200ma, you would have massive kernel instability such as what is described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I **had** the same problem, new Pi 3 model B with original black power supply (*Stontronics +5,1V 2,5A*), connected to the Monitor with HDMI -> VGA adapter (*Club CAC-1300*), with an original SD cart 8GB with NOOBS. After booting, two rainbow screens, one huge in the middle, the second small on the top right corner.

After a deeper investigation I found that the OS on a original SD card (*Build-date: 2015-02-18 NOOBS Version: v1.4*, you can check that in the BUILD-DATA file) is buggy. I have formatted a new SD card (16GB) and unzip the latest NOOBS 2.0.0 on it and then all started to work as expected.

A good tutorial how to prepare a SD cart from scratch with NOOBS can be found here: https://youtu.be/-6OGuhLtKbU?t=702

I wasted a lot of time. What you can be also check and confirm here:
http://forum.modmypi.com/technical-support/raspberry-pi-3-stuck-on-rainbow-screen-t351.html

Comment: Please see the **very copious documentation and discussion** of the small rainbow square [on the Raspberry Pi Foundation's own site](https://www.google.ca/?gws_rd=ssl#q=%22undervoltage+warning%22+%22rainbow+square%22+site:raspberrypi.org).  The fact that something worked for you does not make it universally true, but if you would like to leave an answer of your own, great.

Comment: @goldilocks I am really not sure what do you mean, there are two squares not one as you are referring to, so it means it is totally different case. And from what I noticed one of my colleagues who gets also a new set with an ORIGINAL power supply had the same issue. So it cannot be related with under voltage indicator.
BTW you removed my comment even after I added there a tons of details which were missing from the original post. Please think about that.

Comment: Your link to modmypi *only mentions the rainbow splash screen*, so that is what is "a totally different case" from the actual question here.  The small rainbow square in the upper right corner is **an undervoltage indicator**.  Period.  End of story.  It is not an accidental artifact and its purpose is publicly documented by the people who implemented it.   That *your* problem turned out to be the SD card does not change this fact.

Comment: Honestly I do not want to get to a doctor who, seeing that the patient spits blood and at the same time is bald prescribes medication for dandruff. Once again, congratulations for you diagnosis.  Period ;)

Comment: A closer analogy would be running your car out of gas with flat tires and posting a photograph online to ask people what they think, then when someone points out the tires are flat saying, "Nope! The real problem is I was out of gas!"

Comment: I would like to extend my sincerest gratitude @exproblem, for your tip regarding the buggy SD card. Using the information from the tutorial at the link you provided, I re-formatted the SanDisk 16 GB micro SDHC card (that came with the Raspberry Pi Genius Kit) on my windows machine, (being careful not to use the windows utility to format but to use SD Card Formatter. Then, from the Raspberrypi.org site I downloaded Noobs and installed it onto the newly formatted card. I inserted it into the Pi and Voila! It booted right up with only a big rainbow square very briefly and then into Noobs! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> a little multi-colored square in the top right corner of the screen

That is an under voltage indicator (see, e.g., "Have you got a good power supply?" [at the top here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/display/troubleshooting.md)).

The *big* rainbow square is normally the first thing shown when the pi boots but it should be quickly replaced by the OS, if the OS loads (which it may not if, e.g., there is insufficient power, or an incorrectly formatted SD card).

Note that if the green power LED is flashing in a regular, repeating pattern, or is on solid and not flashing, this *may* indicate a problem with the SD card, but since this could be caused by the power supply problem, you need to get rid of the upper right little rainbow square first.

A few common reasons for that *small* rainbow square would be:

- Insufficient/inappropriate supply; the Pi 3 seems a little more sensitive and demanding this way than other models and may have a peak instantaneous current draw that causes a voltage drop from, e.g., USB *chargers*, which are really intended for charging and not this kind of responsiveness.  You might be able to power a Pi 3 with a minimum of accessories (keyboard, mouse) from a 1.2 amp phone or tablet charger (although beware most phone chargers actually aren't that big), but if it doesn't work, you should try a dedicated 2.5A supply, which is what is recommended.  Unfortunately you may have to order such a supply online.  Although you could check at local hardware and department stores first, what you obviously *don't* want is something with a barrel jack connector.  However, you may be able to find a beefier charger at a store. 2A is not uncommon and may be worth a gamble.
- **Substandard USB cable**.  They aren't all created equal.  While in my experience most of them are okay, some of them are not.  They're fine for charging and data transfer, but charging is not as demanding power wise, and they loose too much voltage.  I have quite a pile, and the ones that have tested as delivering under 4.8V have a bit of tape on them, which might be one in ten.  However, that's just anecdotal and could differ from place to place.

  Some cables actually aren't made for data transfer and only contain power lines for charging, although in this case that doesn't matter because it is all you need.

A lot of electronics supplies are now **5.2V**, to compensate for voltage loss in cables, substandard household circuits, etc.  This includes some device chargers. These are better for the Pi. So if you are buying a new supply, look for that as a priority.

You can check the voltage by measuring with a multi-meter across something attached to a 5V pin from the GPIO breakout and a ground (but don't try and test on the pins themselves as they are too close together and you risk shorting something with normal multi-meter probes). If you do that with your current set-up (which is fine, the pi doesn't have to work), and it is < 4.75V, that is not feasible.

Not that if the thesis that charger voltages are likely to drop because of sudden current draw is correct, passing this test is not evidence that the supply is okay (i.e., it *can* prove the supply *isn't* good enough, but it *can't* prove it *is*).